# WPF progress bar is at 100 % after startup

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, progress-bar

In a WPF application I have defined a progress bar.

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding TotalItemCount}" Value="{Binding CurrentItemCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

However I have the problem that the progress bar is completely filled, i.e. 100 % directly after having started the application although I initially set the properties to the following values:

```
TotalItemCount = 0;
CurrentItemCount = 0;
```

As soon as I change `TotalItemCount` to `1` the progress bar is correctly set to 0 %. It seems to me that the control interpretes 0 from 0 being 100 % .

How can I correct initialze the progress bar to 0 %?

Comment: Well obviously 0 of 0 is 100%. Why not set `TotalItemCount` = 1 as an initial value?

Comment: I would argue that the progress bar does not need to be visible at this point, why not hide it until you are actually loading items?

Comment: The `TotalItemCount` property is bound to another label control displaying the number. If I init this to 1 then the user thinks there is already one item so he has not loaded any data.

Comment: @RudiVisser I'm not good in mathematics but I would think that the progress bar displays a percentage. And `(0/0)*100` is IMHO not defined?

Comment: You've got a maximum of 0 and a value of 0, hence it's hit it's maximum. Maths doesn't really come into play there, though I don't know the internals.

Comment: @Robert When you say that 0/0 is not defined, you exactly get the point. As long as Minimum and Maximum are equal, no valid percentage can be calculated. In other words, any value (be it 0% or 100%) is equally invalid. Therefore you can't say "correctly initialize to 0%". The only solution is not to show the progress bar at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did what some fellows propsed: the progress bar is hidden as long as the counter is 0.

Answer (score 3):

```
public int MaxCountForProgress 
{
  get
  {
    if (TotalItemCount == 0)
      return int.MaxValue;
    return TotalItemCount;
  }
}
```

...

```
ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding MaxCountForProgress}" Value="{Binding CurrentItemCount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: This will fail in case user want to display the current value and maximum value in progress bar.

Comment: I upvoted this answer as it seems reasonable to me ;-) However I'll go with hiding the progress bar until it is really needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a converter for ProgressBar maximum value like this:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(double))]
public class ProgressBarMaximumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((double)value == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null; 
    }
}
```